# How to output decorators in compiled TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator, javascript-decorators

This is an example of a class inside an `index.ts` file that makes use of a decorator i.e `myDecorator`.

```
export class TestClass {
    @myDecorator()
    testFn() {}
}
```

When I compile this using `tsc`, it generates an `index.d.ts` and the output is as follows

```
export declare class TestClass {
    testFn(): void;
}
```

Is it possible to carry the decorator into the output e.g.

```
export declare class TestClass {
    @myDecorator()
    testFn(): void;
}
```

Here is my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "strict": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/__tests__/*"
  ]
}
```

I have tried a number of combinations of trying to carry the decorator to no avail.

Comment: This looks hard like an XY problem. Why do you want that decorator in your types? To me, a decorator makes no sense in the types. What are you trying to do here? What is the decorator supposed to do? OR do you confuse it with metadata? but even that would belong in the compiled JS, not the types.

Comment: Decorators are not part of the type, so it doesn't make sense that they would show up in a file with only type definitions.

Comment: @Thomas - We have a common repository, so was looking to wrap up into a package and use in any consuming repos.

.ts
`` `
@binding()
class ThenSteps {

    @then(/^I wait for the text to be "([^"]*)?" in "([^"]*)?"$/)
    public waitForTextToBe(text: string, selector: string) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

.d.ts
```
declare class ThenSteps {
    waitForTextToBe(text: string, selector: string): Promise<void>;
}
```

The decorator served a purpose allowing our `.feature` files to recognise the regex and then execute the step

Comment: @matthew2564 it's hard to read/understand the code in your snippet without any formatting. But it seems that your decorator adds logic to the method. This logic has been compiled into the `.js` code. The sole purpose of the typings `.d.ts` is to provide the consuming packages with information about the classes/functions that this package provides/exports and their interfaces. *Not to contain any logic whatsoever!*

Answer (score 0):

By definition, tc39 decorator **cannot change the type in any way**, so it's pointless in `d.ts`.

Use JSDoc if you want to mark its usage

```
export class TestClass {
    @myDecorator()
    /** @myDecorated */
    testFn() {}
}
// v //
export class TestClass {
    /** @myDecorated */
    testFn() {}
}
```

Probably that's possible to automate through a typescript code transformer, but I have no experience in them.